# Move dynamically generated content to the top of the page on click. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Take the following dynamically generated content on the left column:

```
<div v-for="index in total" :key="index">
    <h2>Dynamic content: <span v-text="index + ' of ' + total"></span></h2>
</div>
```

And a button in a fixed position at the top right of the page:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 1em; right: 1em;">
    <button v-on:click="autoScrollToDivAtCurrentIndex"></button>
</div>
```

I would like the button to move the next div to the top of the page.

For clarification. The first code block generates n divs in a column to the left. The second div contains a button at a fixed position at the top of the right column. I would like the button to move the 'next' div in the left column to the top of the page on click.

I am using vue.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by giving the div a unique and dynamic id:

```
<div v-for="index in total" :key="index" :id="'id_' + index">
    <h2>Dynamic content: <span v-text="index + ' of ' + total"></span></h2>
</div>
```

Adding the following variable to Vue.js:

```
new Vue({
    nextElement: 1,
}
```

The button itself need not change:

```
<div> style="position: fixed; top: 1em; right: 1em;">
    <button v-on:click="autoScrollToDivAtCurrentIndex"></button>
</div>
```

And the following method:

```
autoScrollToDivAtCurrentIndex(){
    let ele = document.getElementById('id_' + this.nextElement);
    window.scrollTo(ele.offsetLeft,ele.offsetTop);
    this.nextElement++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could inspire from the following solution to achieve your goal, In this case we should move the content not the `div` element because if we want to move the div element that would require CSS code and a some logic to handle that.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    total: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    next: 1
  },
  methods: {
    autoScrollToDivAtCurrentIndex() {

      if (this.next == this.total.length) {
        this.next = 1;
        this.total = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        
      } else {
        this.next++;
        this.total.splice(this.next - 1, 1);
        this.total.unshift(this.next);
      }

    }

  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(c,index) in total" :key="index">
      <h2>Dynamic content: <span v-text="c + ' of ' + total.length"></span></h2>
    </div>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 1em; right: 1em;">
      <button v-on:click="autoScrollToDivAtCurrentIndex" class="btn btn-primary">Move</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```